# PORO from AR Object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

So I got introduced to using PORO instead of AR object for abstraction and size reduction.

But I have so many AR tables didn't make sense to put so much time to build a PORO class for each and every. Would take like a hour or two!! So instead I spent many hours thinking about how can I make this simpler.
And this is what I ended up making:

```
class BasePORO     
  def initialize(obj, immutable = true)  
    self.class::ATTRIBUTES.each do |attr|  
      instance_variable_set("@#{attr}".to_sym, obj.attributes[attr.to_s])  
      instance_eval("undef #{attr}=") if immutable
    end
  end
end

class UserPORO < BasePORO 
  # or plug your own attributes
  ATTRIBUTES = User.new.attributes.keys.map(&:to_sym).freeze  
  attr_accessor(*ATTRIBUTES)
end
```

But I can't somehow move the attr_accessor into the Base class or even ATTRIBUTES when not given explicitly. Not sure if its possible even.

Can I somehow move attr_accessor and default ATTRIBUTES into the main BasePORO class?

Any pointers or feedback is welcome.

Comment: A WHOLE HOUR OMG!!1! What's your actual question?

Comment: Your question should include clear and reproducible behavior, and then an explanation of the behavior that you expect to get vs what you actually get, and what you've done to try to resolve the issue.

Comment: Can I somehow move attr_accessor and default ATTRIBUTES into the main BasePORO class?

Comment: Tried
`ATTRIBUTES = (name.to_s == 'BasePORO') ? [] : name.to_s.remove('PORO').constantize.new.attributes.keys.map(&:to_sym).freeze`
But well constants don't get reinstantiated in children classes.

Comment: Note, there's really no such thing as a "PORO", that's a Java-ism that Ruby doesn't have. In Ruby they're just called simple classes. For cases when you're not dealing with specific attributes, consider using [OpenStruct](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.7.0/libdoc/ostruct/rdoc/OpenStruct.html).

Comment: Another thing: In Ruby it's rare you'll actually *need* `eval`. Here you could do `undef_method(:"#{attr}=")`, or even better, use `attr_reader` instead of `attr_accessor` to avoid creating the mess in the first place.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by moving all the attributes of User  or any other class to make another Object instead of a AR object, would it help in any particular scenario ?

Comment: I think calling `OpenStruct.new(record.attributes)` gives you the same thing, you can call `.freeze` to make it immutable. Also I wonder what is the benefit of this "PORO" exercise.

Comment: Yes, I got it. I was unaware of the convenient OpenStruct before.

Comment: > for abstraction and size reduction.
I'm curious why you'd want to abstract away your domain model? A strong domain model is the basis for a maintainable application. And when it comes to size (probably in memory?), the difference between instantiated objects of different classes should be negligible.
Also, depending on what you are planning to use these simplified models for, you might want to give them appropriate names like "Data Transfer Object" (`BaseDTO'). DTOs are one of the few cases where transforming your domain model into smaller classes makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, `OpenStruct` can do most of the heavy lifting for you. One thing to note is that if you don't `freeze` it, then after it's initialization you'll be able to add more attributes to it throughout its lifetime, e.g.:

```rb
struct = OpenStruct.new(name: "Joe", age: 20)
struct.email = "joe@example.com" # this works
p struct.email # => "joe@example.com"
```

(so essentially it works like a `Hash` with object-like interface)

This behavior may be undesired. And if you do `freeze` the struct, it won't allow any more attributes definition, but then you'd also lose the ability to override existing values (which I think you want to do in cases when someone sets `immutable` to `false`).

For the `immutable` flag to work as I understand you to expect it, I'd create a class that uses `OpenStruct` under its hood, for example like this:

```rb
class BasePORO
  def initialize(obj, immutable = true)
    @immutable = immutable
    @data = OpenStruct.new(obj.attributes)

    obj.attributes.keys.each do |attr|
      self.class.define_method(attr.to_sym) do
        @data.send(attr.to_sym)
      end

      self.class.define_method("#{attr}=".to_sym) do |new_value|
        if @immutable
          raise StandardError.new("#{self} is immutable")
        else
          @data.send("#{attr}=".to_sym, new_value)
        end
      end
    end
  end
end

class UserPORO < BasePORO
end
```

BTW, if you insisted on having a solution similar to the one shown in the question, then you could achieve this with something like that:

```rb
class BasePORO
  def initialize(obj, immutable = true)
    @immutable = immutable

    attributes.each do |attr|
      instance_variable_set("@#{attr}".to_sym, obj.attributes[attr.to_s])

      self.class.define_method(attr.to_sym) do
        instance_variable_get("@#{attr}".to_sym)
      end

      self.class.define_method("#{attr}=".to_sym) do |new_value|
        if @immutable
          raise StandardError.new("#{self} is immutable")
        else
          instance_variable_set("@#{attr}".to_sym, new_value)
        end
      end
    end
  end

  private

  # default attributes
  def attributes
    [:id]
  end
end

class UserPORO < BasePORO

  private

  # overriding default attributes from BasePORO
  def attributes
    User.new.attributes.keys.map(&:to_sym).freeze
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I added more crazy and ended up with something I can't post in this comment! I'll post in an answer

Answer (score 0):

So this is what actually ended up with:

```
class BaseStruct < OpenStruct
  def initialize(model, immutable: true, only: [], includes: [])
    if only.empty?
      hash = model.attributes
    else
      hash = model.attributes.slice(*only.map!(&:to_s))
    end
    includes.each do |i|
      relation = model.public_send(i)
      if relation.respond_to?(:each)
        hash[i.to_s] = relation.map{|r| OpenStruct.new(r.attributes).freeze}
      else
        hash[i.to_s] = OpenStruct.new(relation.attributes).freeze
      end
    end
    super(hash)
    self.freeze if immutable
  end
end
```

Feel free to critique or suggest improvements.